# have ubuntu want kubuntu

Tags: command-line, package-management, kubuntu

Earlier today i was messing around with ubuntu and found a package that gave me a graphic box with different version in it like ubuntu xubuntu kubuntu and so on.
I found it very useful as you could install one and remove the other at the same time, But the main problem is now i can't seem to find it again and i've searched google but can't find a post about it either which sucks.

Does anyone know what this package is call and the terminal code to get it to run.

Comment: No that wasn't what i was after either lol Well in the end i fully install kubuntu and removed ubuntu, as i liked the look for the desktop and that, but ran into a few problems in getting adobe flashplayer plugin 11 installed and went back to ubuntu this morning. Thank you for all the tips though :)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're talking about is having different desktop environments, that you can choose on login.  If that's the case, then just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install kde-standard
```

To install the KDE Desktop Graphical Environment

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

To install the XFCE Desktop Graphical Environment

Once you install the one you like, or both, go ahead and logout, and when you're ready to log back in, choose the environment the you want to try, and login, as shown in the images below.

[image]
[image]

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda sounds like the closest thing to what you want is VirtualBox.

To install it just search google for 'VirtualBox', it'll come up.

All you have to do is have the VirtualBox Virtual HDD ready and then the ISO of the OS you want to use. Very simple and allows you to quickly and efficiently run different OSes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can't remember where i found it but once i had it installed i had to run a command for the terminal and a purple box came up with different flavours of ubuntu on it like ubuntu xubunt and so on i remember one of the options was kubuntu and kubunt-full or something like that.

you could select as many things as you like but what i done was deselected ubuntu and selected kubuntu then clicked ok and an install process started when it got to 17% it asked me what to pick KDE or KDM one of them and GDM.
After i picked it ran through and installed kubuntu and also it fully removed ubuntu.